# Export Grouped Data on Excel

Tags: module, odoo, add-on, odoo-12

Is the any way or module to export on xls grouped data?

**Example:**

[image]

I want to export e.g. only this 3 lines

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You will have to select the records otherwise the program will not be able to detect which records you want to export.

Comment: i found a solution i made a module to export the grouped lines

Comment: Please share your solution.

Comment: i made a button to call a custom wizzard to export the data. i think you cant export the lines as it showing on above image (atleast i didnt find a way)